# Python Default Inheritance?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

If I define a class in Python such as:

```
class AClass:
   __slots__ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Which class does it inherit from? It doesn't seem to inherit from `object`.

Comment: All of the answers regarding `object` and old vs new classes are right, but why do you ask? Is there a practical reason or is it just a philosophical/language-design question? (Because in most cases, it doesn't matter!)

Comment: What version of Python?  Python 2 and Python 3 do this differently.

Comment: I think I was trying to extend this class, but it wouldn't let me extend it until I made it inherit from Object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you define a class and don't declare any specific parent, the class becomes a "classic class", which behaves a bit differently than "new-style classes" inherited from object. See here for more details: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html

Classic classes don't have a common root, so essentially, your AClass doesn't inherit from any class.

Note that this is specific to Python versions before 3.0. In Python 3, all classes are new-style classes and inherit implicitly from object, if no other parent is declared.

Answer (score 10):

Try the following code snippet in Python 2.7 and Python 3.1

```
class AClass:
   __slots__ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(type(AClass))
print(issubclass(AClass,object))
print(isinstance(AClass,type))
```

In Python 2.7, you will get:

```
<type 'classobj'>
False
False
```

And Python 3.1 you will get.

```
<class type>
True
True
```

And that explains it all. It is old style class in Python 2, unless you subclass it from `object`. Only in Python3, it will be treated like a new style class by default.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x or older, your example `AClass` is an "old-style" class.

A "new-style" class has a defined inheritance and must inherit from object or some other class.

[What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

EDIT: Wow, I didn't think it was possible to use the old-style syntax in Python 3.x.  But I just tried it and that syntax still works.  But you get a new-style class.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try it out.

```
>>> class AClass:
...     pass
... 
>>> AClass.__bases__, type(AClass)
( (), <type 'classobj'> )                # inherits from nothing

>>> class AClass(object):                # new style inherits from object
...     pass
... 
>>> AClass.__bases__, type(AClass)
( (<type 'object'>,), <type 'type'> )
```

Read an introduction to the new style classes in the links given in other answers.