# Use @StaticMethods in serializer Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers which use a same function. I want to define it as a static method and reuse it.

**Serializer for Article**

```
class ArticleDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    liked = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'id',
            'self_liked',
            'title'
        ]

    def get_liked(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        self_like_obj = Reaction.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='article'), object_id=obj.id)
        if self_like_obj.exists():
            self_like = Reaction.objects.get(user=request.user.id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='article'), object_id=obj.id).react_type
        else:
            self_like = False
        return self_like
```

**Serializer for comment**

```
class CommentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        liked = SerializerMethodField()
        class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = [
                'id',
                'self_liked',
                'content'
            ]

        def get_liked(self, obj):
            request = self.context.get('request')
            self_like_obj = Reaction.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='comment'), object_id=obj.id)
            if self_like_obj.exists():
                self_like = Reaction.objects.get(user=request.user.id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='comment'), object_id=obj.id).react_type
            else:
                self_like = False
            return self_like
```

As you see, two serializer use a general function: `get_liked` How can I define it as a static methods for reuse?

Comment: I dont think staticmethod is what you really need in this case. You can implement method only once in mixin class, and use this class as parent for both serializers.

Comment: Could you please write it for me? I'm a beginner with Django Rest Framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **@neverwalkaloner** suggested you can implement method only once in mixin class, and use this class as parent for both serializers. Keep in mind that your `get_liked` method is not the same in `ArticleDetailSerializer`and `CommentSerializer` serializers.

`ArticleDetailSerializer` method has `ContentType.objects.get(model='article')` line but `CommentSerializer` has `ContentType.objects.get(model='comment')` which makes the difference between `get_liked` method from your serializers.

You can use the same mixin that **@neverwalkaloner** suggested but instead of `ContentType.objects.get(model='article')` and `ContentType.objects.get(model='comment')` lines you can try with `ContentType.objects.get(model=self.Meta.model.__name__.lower())`.

I think it should look like this:

```
class LikedMixin(object):

    def get_lowercased_model_name(self, obj):
        return self.Meta.model.__name__.lower()

    def get_liked(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        model_name = self.get_lowercased_model_name()
        self_like_obj = Reaction.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, content_type=model_name, object_id=obj.id)
        if self_like_obj.exists():
            self_like = Reaction.objects.get(user=request.user.id, content_type=model_name, object_id=obj.id).react_type
        else:
            self_like = False
        return self_like
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `get_liked` method in mixin class and use this class as parent for both serializers like this:

```
class LikesMixin:
    def get_liked(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        self_like_obj = Reaction.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='comment'), object_id=obj.id)
        if self_like_obj.exists():
            self_like = Reaction.objects.get(user=request.user.id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='comment'), object_id=obj.id).react_type
        else:
            self_like = False
        return self_like

class CommentSerializer(ModelSerializer, LikesMixin):
    liked = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'id',
            'self_liked',
            'content'
        ]

class ArticleDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer, LikesMixin):
    liked = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'id',
            'self_liked',
            'title'
        ]
```

Comment: hi, I'm asking this for a clarification,  shouldn't the **model** change in the **class likesMixin**

Comment: @PabasaraRanathunga no, you define model inside each serializer class separately.

Comment: `=ContentType.objects.get(model='comment')` I was referring to this part. could you please explain a little.

Comment: @PabasaraRanathunga OP using generic relations see details here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations. You dont need this in your mixin, just replace method completely with one you are using.

Comment: Unless the code is for Python 3 only, [the mixin class should inherit from `object`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38139275/253599).

Comment: This answer missed an opportunity to apply the field declaration to the mixin, rather than applying it on each serializer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of when to use a [mixin class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547714/253599).  The mixin is a new class which contains methods and class attributes you want to use in other classes, like this:

```
class LikedMixin(object):
    liked = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_liked(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        self_like_obj = Reaction.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='article'), object_id=obj.id)
        if self_like_obj.exists():
            self_like = Reaction.objects.get(user=request.user.id, content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='article'), object_id=obj.id).react_type
        else:
            self_like = False
        return self_like
```

You may then declare your serializers to inherit from your mixin:

```
class ArticleDetailSerializer(LikedMixin, ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'id',
            'self_liked',
            'title'
        ]

class CommentSerializer(LikedMixin, ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'id',
            'self_liked',
            'content'
        ]
```

It might be a good idea to familiarise yourself with the basics of [method resolution order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277407/253599), in order to recognise any potential issues relating to multiple inheritance down the track.